Issue facing the tile movement - Flappy Bird - Java Game Programming
I am trying to develop a flappy bird game. Now I am facing an issue with background movement. With respect to my code, the bird is moving, then the background is moving. My game world will need to be greater in size than the physical windowed game size. In this type
of game, the world should appear to move around the player rather than the player move around
the world (the player will appear stationary as the world moves underneath them).Can anyone please help me to move the background from right top left. Here a cloud moving from right to left.That is working. But background tile movement is not happening.
 import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequence;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;

import java.awt.*;


import game2D.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends GameCore 
{
 // Useful game constants
 static int screenWidth = 612;
 static int screenHeight = 484;

 // Game constants
 float   lift = 0.005f;
 float   gravity = 0.0001f;
 float   fly = -0.04f;
 float   moveSpeed = 0.05f;
 
 // Game state flags
 boolean flap = false;
 boolean moveRight = false;
 boolean debug = true;       

 // Game resources
 Animation landing;
 
 Sprite  player = null;
 ArrayList<Sprite>   clouds = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
 ArrayList<Tile>     collidedTiles = new ArrayList<Tile>();

 TileMap tmap = new TileMap();   // Our tile map, note that we load it in init()
 
 long total;                     // The score will be the total time elapsed since a crash
 private boolean gameOver = false;
 private Sound backgroundSound;
 private Sound gameOverSound;
 private Sequencer sequencer; // For playing MIDI music

 /**
  * The obligatory main method that creates
  * an instance of our class and starts it running
  * 
  * @param args  The list of parameters this program might use (ignored)
  */
 public static void main(String[] args) {

     Game gct = new Game();
     gct.init();
     // Start in windowed mode with the given screen height and width
     gct.run(false,screenWidth,screenHeight);
 }

 /**
  * Initialise the class, e.g. set up variables, load images,
  * create animations, register event handlers.
  * 
  * This shows you the general principles but you should create specific
  * methods for setting up your game that can be called again when you wish to 
  * restart the game (for example you may only want to load animations once
  * but you could reset the positions of sprites each time you restart the game).
  */
 public void init()
 {         
     Sprite s;   // Temporary reference to a sprite

     // Load the tile map and print it out so we can check it is valid
     tmap.loadMap("maps", "map.txt");
     
     setSize(tmap.getPixelWidth()/4, tmap.getPixelHeight());
     adjustWindowSize(); // Adjust window size to match game size
     setVisible(true);

     // Create a set of background sprites that we can 
     // rearrange to give the illusion of motion
     
     landing = new Animation();
     landing.loadAnimationFromSheet("images/landbird.png", 4, 1, 60);
     
     // Initialise the player with an animation
     player = new Sprite(landing);
     
     // Load a single cloud animation
     Animation ca = new Animation();
     ca.addFrame(loadImage("images/cloud.png"), 1000);
     
     // Create 3 clouds at random positions off the screen
     // to the right
     for (int c=0; c<3; c++)
     {
         s = new Sprite(ca);
         s.setX(screenWidth + (int)(Math.random()*200.0f));
         s.setY(30 + (int)(Math.random()*150.0f));
         s.setVelocityX(-0.02f);
         s.show();
         clouds.add(s);
     }
    
     initialiseGame();
         
     System.out.println(tmap);
     try {
         sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
         sequencer.open();
         InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("background.mid");
         if (is != null) {
             Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(is);
             sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
             sequencer.start(); // Start playback
         } else {
             System.err.println("MIDI file not found");
         }
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     
 }

 /**
  * You will probably want to put code to restart a game in
  * a separate method so that you can call it when restarting
  * the game when the player loses.
  */
 public void initialiseGame()
 {
     total = 0;
           
     player.setPosition(200,200);
     player.setVelocity(0,0);
     player.show();
     gameOver=false;
     // Start playing background music
     if (sequencer != null && sequencer.isOpen()) {
         sequencer.stop(); // Stop the music if it's currently playing
         sequencer.setMicrosecondPosition(0); // Rewind the music to the beginning
         sequencer.start(); // Start playing from the beginning
         sequencer.setLoopCount(Sequencer.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
     }
 }
 /**
  * Adjusts the size of the window to match the size of the game.
  */
 private void adjustWindowSize() {
     Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

     // Set the game size to match the tile map size
     int gameWidth = tmap.getPixelWidth();
     int gameHeight = tmap.getPixelHeight();

     // Calculate the position to center the game on the screen
     int x = (screenSize.width - gameWidth) / 2;
     int y = (screenSize.height - gameHeight) / 2;

     // Update the size of the window to match the game rectangle
     setSize(gameWidth, gameHeight);
     setLocation(x, y);
 }




 /**
  * Draw the current state of the game. Note the sample use of
  * debugging output that is drawn directly to the game screen.
  */
 public void draw(Graphics2D g)
 {       
     // Be careful about the order in which you draw objects - you
     // should draw the background first, then work your way 'forward'

     // First work out how much we need to shift the view in order to
     // see where the player is. To do this, we adjust the offset so that
     // it is relative to the player's position along with a shift
     int xo = -(int)player.getX() + 200;
     int yo = -(int)player.getY() + 200;

     g.setColor(Color.white);
     g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
     g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 10));

     // Apply offsets to sprites then draw them
     for (Sprite s: clouds)
     {
         s.setOffsets(xo,yo);
         s.draw(g);
     }

     // Apply offsets to tile map and draw  it
     tmap.draw(g,xo,yo); 

     // Apply offsets to player and draw 
     player.setOffsets(xo, yo);
     player.draw(g);
             
     
     // Show score and status information
     String msg = String.format("Score: %d", total/100);
     g.setColor(Color.darkGray);
     g.drawString(msg, getWidth() - 100, 50);
     
     if (debug)
     {

         // When in debug mode, you could draw borders around objects
         // and write messages to the screen with useful information.
         // Try to avoid printing to the console since it will produce 
         // a lot of output and slow down your game.
         tmap.drawBorder(g, xo, yo, Color.black);

         g.setColor(Color.red);
         player.drawBoundingBox(g);
     
         g.drawString(String.format("Player: %.0f,%.0f", player.getX(),player.getY()),
                                     getWidth() - 100, 70);
         
         drawCollidedTiles(g, tmap, xo, yo);
     }

 }

 public void drawCollidedTiles(Graphics2D g, TileMap map, int xOffset, int yOffset)
 {
     if (collidedTiles.size() > 0)
     {   
         
         int tileWidth = map.getTileWidth();
         int tileHeight = map.getTileHeight();
         
         g.setColor(Color.blue);
         for (Tile t : collidedTiles)
         {
             g.drawRect(t.getXC()+xOffset, t.getYC()+yOffset, tileWidth, tileHeight);
         }
         player.setPosition(player.getX(), player.getY());
         showGameOver(g);
         showRestartOption(g);
         gameOver = true; // Set game over flag  
     }
 }
 public void showGameOver(Graphics2D g) {
     g.setColor(Color.RED);
     String gameOverMessage = "Game Over, Your score is "+total;
     
     int x = (screenWidth - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(gameOverMessage)) / 2;
     int y = screenHeight / 2;
     g.drawString(gameOverMessage, x, y);
    
     
  // Stop background music
     if (sequencer != null && sequencer.isOpen()) {
         sequencer.stop();
     }
     
 }
 public void showRestartOption(Graphics2D g) {
     g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
     String restartMessage = "Press Enter to Restart";
     int x = (screenWidth - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(restartMessage)) / 2;
     int y = screenHeight / 2 + 30;
     g.drawString(restartMessage, x, y);
 }
 /**
  * Update any sprites and check for collisions
  * 
  * @param elapsed The elapsed time between this call and the previous call of elapsed
  */    
 public void update(long elapsed) {
     boolean playerMoved = false;

     // Check if the player has reached the right edge of the screen
     if (player.getX() + player.getWidth() >= tmap.getPixelWidth()) {
         // Move player to the left side of the screen
         player.setX(0);

         // Repeat the background sprite by adjusting the x position of the clouds
         for (Sprite s : clouds) {
             s.setX(s.getX() - tmap.getPixelWidth()); // Move the cloud sprite back by the width of the map
             s.update(elapsed);
         }
     }

     // Update player's movement and track if it moves horizontally
     if (flap || moveRight) {
         playerMoved = true;
         player.setVelocityY(player.getVelocityY() + (gravity * elapsed));
         player.setAnimationSpeed(1.0f);
         if (flap) {
             player.setAnimationSpeed(1.8f);
             player.setVelocityY(fly);
         }
         if (moveRight) {
             player.setVelocityX(moveSpeed);
         }
     }

     // Update total score based on player's movement
     if (!gameOver && playerMoved) {
         total += elapsed; // Increment the total score by the elapsed time
     }

     // Make adjustments to the speed of the sprite due to gravity
     player.setVelocityY(player.getVelocityY() + (gravity * elapsed));

     player.setAnimationSpeed(1.0f);

     if (flap) {
         player.setAnimationSpeed(1.8f);
         player.setVelocityY(fly);
     }

     if (moveRight) {
         player.setVelocityX(moveSpeed);
     } else {
         player.setVelocityX(0);
     }

     // Update the clouds
     for (Sprite s : clouds) {
         s.update(elapsed);
         if (s.getX() + s.getWidth() < 0) {
             // If the cloud has moved off the left side of the screen
             // Move it to the right side of the screen
             s.setX(screenWidth);
             // Optionally, randomize the Y position to create variety
             s.setY(30 + (int)(Math.random() * 150.0f));
         }
     }

     // Update the player's animation and position
     player.update(elapsed);

     // Then check for any collisions that may have occurred
     handleScreenEdge(player, tmap, elapsed);
     checkTileCollision(player, tmap);
 }


 
 
 /**
  * Checks and handles collisions with the edge of the screen. You should generally
  * use tile map collisions to prevent the player leaving the game area. This method
  * is only included as a temporary measure until you have properly developed your
  * tile maps.
  * 
  * @param s         The Sprite to check collisions for
  * @param tmap      The tile map to check 
  * @param elapsed   How much time has gone by since the last call
  */
 public void handleScreenEdge(Sprite s, TileMap tmap, long elapsed)
 {
     // This method just checks if the sprite has gone off the bottom screen.
     // Ideally you should use tile collision instead of this approach
     
     float heightDifference = s.getY() + s.getHeight() - tmap.getPixelHeight();
     if (heightDifference > 0)
     {
         // Put the player back on the map according to how far over they were
         s.setY(tmap.getPixelHeight() - s.getHeight() - (int)(heightDifference)); 
         
         // and make them bounce
         s.setVelocityY(-s.getVelocityY()*0.75f);
     }
     float widthDifference = s.getX() + s.getWidth() - tmap.getPixelWidth();
     if (widthDifference > 0)
     {
         // Put the player back on the map according to how far over they were
         s.setX(tmap.getPixelWidth() - s.getWidth() - (int)(widthDifference)); 
         
         // and make them bounce
         s.setVelocityX(-s.getVelocityX()*0.75f);
     }
     
 }
 
 
  
 /**
  * Override of the keyPressed event defined in GameCore to catch our
  * own events
  * 
  *  @param e The event that has been generated
  */
 public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
 { 
     int key = e.getKeyCode();
     
     if (gameOver) { // Check if the game is over 
         if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
             initialiseGame(); // Restart the game
         }
         return;
     }
     
     switch (key) {
         case KeyEvent.VK_UP     : flap = true; break;
         case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT  : moveRight = true; break;
         case KeyEvent.VK_S      : Sound s = new Sound("sounds/caw.wav"); 
                                   s.start();
                                   break;                
         case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE : stop(); break;
         case KeyEvent.VK_B      : debug = !debug; break; // Flip the debug state
         default :  break;
     }
 
 }

 /** Use the sample code in the lecture notes to properly detect
  * a bounding box collision between sprites s1 and s2.
  * 
  * @return  true if a collision may have occurred, false if it has not.
  */
 public boolean boundingBoxCollision(Sprite s1, Sprite s2)
 {
     return false;       
 }
 
 /**
  * Check and handles collisions with a tile map for the
  * given sprite 's'. Initial functionality is limited...
  * 
  * @param s         The Sprite to check collisions for
  * @param tmap      The tile map to check 
  */

 public void checkTileCollision(Sprite s, TileMap tmap)
 {
     // Empty out our current set of collided tiles
     collidedTiles.clear();
     
     // Take a note of a sprite's current position
     float sx = s.getX();
     float sy = s.getY();
     
     // Find out how wide and how tall a tile is
     float tileWidth = tmap.getTileWidth();
     float tileHeight = tmap.getTileHeight();
     
     // Divide the sprite’s x coordinate by the width of a tile, to get
     // the number of tiles across the x axis that the sprite is positioned at 
     int xtile = (int)(sx / tileWidth);
     // The same applies to the y coordinate
     int ytile = (int)(sy / tileHeight);
     
     // What tile character is at the top left of the sprite s?
     Tile tl = tmap.getTile(xtile, ytile);
     
     
     if (tl != null && tl.getCharacter() != '.') // If it's not a dot (empty space), handle it
     {
         // Here we just stop the sprite. 
         s.stop();
         collidedTiles.add(tl);
         
         // You should move the sprite to a position that is not colliding
     }
     
     // We need to consider the other corners of the sprite
     // The above looked at the top left position, let's look at the bottom left.
     xtile = (int)(sx / tileWidth);
     ytile = (int)((sy + s.getHeight())/ tileHeight);
     Tile bl = tmap.getTile(xtile, ytile);
     
     // If it's not empty space
     if (bl != null && bl.getCharacter() != '.') 
     {
         // Let's make the sprite bounce
         s.setVelocityY(-s.getVelocityY()*0.6f); // Reverse velocity 
         collidedTiles.add(bl);
     }
 }


 public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { 

     int key = e.getKeyCode();

     switch (key)
     {
         case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE : stop(); break;
         case KeyEvent.VK_UP     : flap = false; break;
         case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT  : moveRight = false; break;
         default :  break;
     }
 }
 public void stop() {
     // Stop background music
     if (sequencer != null && sequencer.isOpen()) {
         sequencer.stop();
     }
 }
}


import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.*;



/**
 * TileMap enables you to load a character based tile map from a text file. An
 * example of the format for such a text file is given below:

10 5 32 32
// The first line should contain the width and height of the
// map and the width and height of each tile. A list of character to
// tile mappings is then provided where each character is preceded by a
// # character. The dot character always defaults to a blank space 
// Note that the referenced files should be in the same directory as the
// tile map.
#b=orangeblock.png
#c=greencircle.png
#g=glasses.png
// The actual tile map is preceded by the #map line
#map
bbbbbbbbbb
b........b
b..g.....b
bccccccccb
bbbbbbbbbb

}
 * @author David Cairns
 */
public class TileMap 
{

    private Tile [][] tmap;     // The tile map grid, initially null
    private int mapWidth=0;     // The maps width in tiles
    private int mapHeight=0;    // The maps height in tiles
    private int tileWidth=0;    // The width of a tile in pixels
    private int tileHeight=0;   // The height of a tile in pixels
    
    // imagemap contains a set of character to image mappings for
    // quick loop up of the image associated with a given character.
    private Map<String,Image> imagemap = new HashMap<String,Image>();
    
    /**
     * @return The map height in tiles
     */
    public int getMapHeight() {
        return mapHeight;
    }

    /**
     * @return The map width in tiles
     */
    public int getMapWidth() {
        return mapWidth;
    }
    
    /**
     * @return The height of a tile in pixels.
     */
    public int getTileHeight() {
        return tileHeight;
    }

    /**
     * @return The width of a tile in pixels.
     */
    public int getTileWidth() {
        return tileWidth;
    }

    /**
     * @return The map height in pixels
     */
    public int getPixelHeight() {
        return mapHeight * tileHeight;
    }

    /**
     * @return The map width in pixels
     */
    public int getPixelWidth() {
        return mapWidth * tileWidth;
    }
    
    /**
     * Loads a 'mapfile' that is contained in the given 'folder'. It is expected that
     * the images associated with the map will also be in 'folder'.
     *  
     * @param folder The folder the tile map and images are located in
     * @param mapfile The name of the map file in the map folder
     * @return true if the map loaded successfully, false otherwise
     */
    public boolean loadMap(String folder, String mapfile)
    {
        // Create a full path to the tile map by sticking the folder and mapfile together
        String path = folder + "/" + mapfile;
        int row=0;
        
        try
        {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
            String line="";
            String trimmed="";
            String [] vals;
            
            // First we need to clear out the old image map
            imagemap.clear();
            
            // Read the first line of the tile map to find out
            // the relevant dimensions of the map plus the tiles
            line = in.readLine();
            vals = line.split(" ");
            // Check that we read 4 values
            if (vals.length != 4)
            {
                System.err.println("Incorrect number of parameters in the TileMap header:" + vals.length);
                in.close();
                return false;
            }
            
            // Read in the map dimensions
            mapWidth = Integer.parseInt(vals[0]);
            mapHeight = Integer.parseInt(vals[1]);
            tileWidth = Integer.parseInt(vals[2]);
            tileHeight = Integer.parseInt(vals[3]);
            
            // Now look for the character assignments
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                trimmed = line.trim();
                // Skip the current line if it's a comment
                if (trimmed.startsWith("//")) continue;
                // Break out of the loop if we find the map
                if (trimmed.startsWith("#map")) break;
                
                if (trimmed.charAt(0) == '#') // Look for a character to image map
                {
                    // Extract the character
                    
                    String ch = "" + trimmed.charAt(1);
                    // and it's file name
                    String fileName = trimmed.substring(3,trimmed.length());
                    
                    Image img  = new ImageIcon(folder + "/" + fileName).getImage();
                    // Now add this character->image mapping to the map
                    if (img != null)
                        imagemap.put(ch,img);
                    else
                        System.err.println("Failed to load image '" + folder + "/" + fileName + "'");
                }
            }
            
            // Check the map dimensione are at least > 0
            if ((mapWidth > 0) && (mapHeight > 0))
            {
                tmap = new Tile[mapWidth][mapHeight]; 
            }
            else
            {
                System.err.println("Incorrect image map dimensions.");
                trimmed = "";
            }
            
            // Now read in the tile map structure
            if (trimmed.startsWith("#map"))
            {
                row=0;
                while ((line = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.trim().startsWith("//")) continue;
                
                    if (line.length() != mapWidth)
                    {
                        System.err.println("Incorrect line length in map");
                        System.err.println(row + " : " + line);
                        continue;
                    }
                    
                    for (int col=0; col<mapWidth && col<line.length(); col++)
                        tmap[col][row] = new Tile(line.charAt(col),col*tileWidth,row*tileHeight);
                    row++;
                    
                    if (row >= mapHeight) break;
                }
            }
            
            in.close();
            
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println("Failed to read in tile map '" + path + "':" + e);
            return false;
        }
        
        if (row != mapHeight)
        {
            System.err.println("Map failed to load. Incorrect rows in map");
            return false;
        }
        
        return true;
    }
    
    /**
     * Generate the tile map as a String so we can inspect its current state
     */
    public String toString()
    {
        StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
        for (int r=0; r<mapHeight; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<mapWidth; c++)
                s.append(tmap[c][r].getCharacter());
    
            s.append('\n');
        }
        return s.toString();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the Image object associated with the tile at position 'x','y'
     * 
     * @param x The x tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @param y The y tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @return The Image object associated with the tile at position 'x,y', null if blank or not found
     */
    public Image getTileImage(int x, int y)
    {
        if (!valid(x,y)) return null;
        Tile t = tmap[x][y];
        if (t == null) return null;
        char ch = t.getCharacter();
        if (ch == '.') return null; // Blank space
        return imagemap.get(ch + "");
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the top left pixel x coordinate of a tile at position 'x,y' in the tile map
     *  
     * @param x The x tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @param y The y tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @return The top left pixel x coordinate of a tile at position 'x,y' in the tile map
     */
    public int getTileXC(int x, int y)
    {
        if (!valid(x,y)) return 0;
        return tmap[x][y].getXC();
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the top left pixel y coordinate of a tile at position 'x,y' in the tile map
     *  
     * @param x The x tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @param y The y tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @return The top left pixel y coordinate of a tile at position 'x,y' in the tile map
     */ 
    public int getTileYC(int x, int y)
    {
        if (!valid(x,y)) return 0;
        return tmap[x][y].getYC();
    }
    
    /**
     * 
     * @param x The x tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @param y The y tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @return true if tile coordinate 'x,y' is a valid position in the tile map
     */
    public boolean valid(int x, int y)
    {
        return (x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x<mapWidth && y<mapHeight);
    }
    
    /**
     * Sets the tile character at position 'x,y' to the value of 'ch'.
     * 
     * @param ch The character to set the tile to.
     * @param x The x tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @param y The y tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @return true if the character was correctly set
     */
    public boolean setTileChar(char ch, int x, int y)
    {
        if (!valid(x,y)) return false;
        tmap[x][y].setCharacter(ch);
        return true;
    }
    
    /**
     * Gets the tile character at position 'x,y'
     * 
     * @param x The x tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @param y The y tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @return The character the tile is currently set to.
     */
    public char getTileChar(int x, int y)
    {
        if (!valid(x,y)) return '?';
        return tmap[x][y].getCharacter();
    }

    /**
     * Gets the tile object at position 'x,y'
     * 
     * @param x The x tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @param y The y tile coordinate (in tiles, not pixels)
     * @return The tile object at position 'x,y'.
     */
    public Tile getTile(int x, int y)
    {
        if (!valid(x,y)) return null;
        return tmap[x][y];
    }
    
    /**
     * Draws the tile map to the graphics device pointed to by 'g'.
     * 
     * @param g The graphics device to draw to
     * @param xoff The xoffset to shift the tile map by
     * @param yoff The yoffset to shift the tile map by
     */
    public void draw(Graphics2D g, int xoff, int yoff)
    {
        if (g == null) return;
    
        Image img=null;
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)g.getClip();
        int xc,yc;
        
        for (int r=0; r<mapHeight; r++)
        {
            for (int c=0; c<mapWidth; c++)
            {
                img = getTileImage(c, r);
                if (img == null) continue;
                xc = xoff + c*tileWidth;
                yc = yoff + r*tileHeight;
                
                // Only draw the tile if it is on screen, otherwise go back round the loop
                if (xc+tileWidth < 0 || xc >= rect.x + rect.width) continue;
                if (yc+tileHeight < 0 || yc >= rect.y + rect.height) continue;
                g.drawImage(img,xc,yc,null);
            }
        }       
    }
    
    /**
     * Draw a border around the tile map using the given colour and offsets.
     * This may be useful for debugging purposes.
     * 
     * @param g The graphics device to draw to
     * @param xoff The xoffset to shift the tile map by
     * @param yoff The yoffset to shift the tile map by
     * @param colour The colour to draw the border with
     */
    public void drawBorder(Graphics2D g, int xoff, int yoff, Color colour)
    {
        if (g == null) return;
            
        g.setColor(colour);
        g.drawRect(xoff, yoff, getPixelWidth(), getPixelHeight());      
    }
    
}


Make a fixed interval update method in your Game class, say FixedUpdate, have another class, say FixedUpdater, extend the TimerTask class. This FixedUpdater will just call the fixed update method in a method called run. Than back in your Game class, upon the start of the game, set the FixedUpdate to run on regular intervals. And spawn your first scrolling background sprite. Make the sprite with the same or a similar class as your clouds. Make sure that the left and right sides match up correctly, or the seam between the 2 sprites will be clear. Within the FixedUpdate method, spawn the custom background sprite once the old one has finished scrolling. Below is some rough code that should communicate the idea, but may not work with your libraries.
import java.time.*;
public class FixedUpdater extends TimerTasK{
    public void run(){
        Game.FixedUpdate();
    }
}

public class Game{
    double elapsedTime = 0; // seconds
    double fixedUpdateInterval = 1/30; // seconds
    int imgSpeed = -100; // pixels per second 
    int worldWidth = 1000; // pixels
    int worldHeight = 400; // pixels
    int imgWidth = 3000; // pixels
    int imgHeigt = 400; // pixels

    public Game(){
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new FixedUpdater(), 0, 1 * 1000);
        // runs the FixedUpdater's run method every 1 seconds
        new Image(worldWidth * 1.1, 0, imgSpeed, 0, Sprite.background);
        // (x, y, xspeed, yspeed, sprite to show);
        /* assumes the 0,0 is top left of screen and the constructors     
        positions are for the top left corner of the image*/
    }

    public void FixedUpdate(){
        elapsedTime += fixedUpdateInterval;
        if(elapsedTime % (imgWidth / imgSpeed) = 0){
            new Image(worldWidth * 1.1, 0, imgSpeed, 0, Sprite.background);
        }
    }   
}

Be careful to make sure your image isn't scrolling too fast. In the code above, an individual pixels's speed if the screen is a length of 1, is worldwidth / imgSpeed. In the code this is 10, and since the units used are seconds, an individual pixel on the background will cross the user's screen in 10 seconds. Also make sure you deference a sprite once it reaches the edge of the screen to save memory and processing power.
